# Overwriting a file in python

Tags: python, file-io, overwrite

I'm trying to over write a file in python so it only keeps the most up to date information read from a serial port.  I've tried several different methods and read quite a few different posts but the file keeps writing the information over and over with out overwriting the previous entry.

```
 import serial

 ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',57600)

 target=open( 'wxdata' , 'w+' )

 with ser as port, target as outf:
      while 1:
           target.truncate()
           outf.write(ser.read))
           outf.flush()
```

I have a weather station sending data wirelessly to a raspberry pi,  I just want the file to keep one line of current data received.  right now it just keeps looping and adding over and over. Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: open the file in the loop if you want to overwrite each time or `file.seek(0) file.truncate(0)file.write`

Comment: You are also missing parens on `ser.read` `ser.read()`

Answer (score 3):

I would change your code to look like:

```
from serial import Serial

with Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',57600) as port:
    while True:
        with open('wxdata', 'w') as file:
            file.write(port.read())
```

This will make sure it gets truncated, flushed, etc. Why do work you don't have to? :)

Answer (score 1):

By default, `truncate()` only truncates the file *to the current position*. Which, with your loop, is only at 0 the first time through. Change your loop to:

```
while 1:
    outf.seek(0)
    outf.truncate()
    outf.write(ser.read())
    outf.flush()
```

Note that `truncate()` does accept an optional size argument, which you could pass 0 for, but you'd still need to seek back to the beginning before writing the next part anyway.

Comment: @Padraic: Hmm, yeah thanks. I copy pasted without reading too closely ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Before you start writing the file, add the following line:

```
outf.seek(0)
outf.truncate()
```

This will make it so that whatever you write next will overwrite the file

Comment: Careful with this in general -- if what you write next is shorter than what was there before, only the start of the file will be overwritten! The call to `truncate()` is necessary too.